# Not allowed to load local resource with OpenID connect redirection

Tags: android, cordova, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm stuck with a `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/index.html?code=[code]&state=[state]` when the Authentication API, using OpenID Connect standard, is trying to redirect to my local Android application.

When I launch my application, if I am not connected yet, a redirection is performed to an Authentication API which asks for the user credentials. Then, if the credentials were good, the API will perform another redirection to the `redirectUri` passed in the first redirection (as a query parameter). This `redirectUri` is the previous `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`.

I don't know how to configure my app/phone to let a remote application (the Authentication API) redirect to my app after a successful authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options available to accomplish this. Looking at the ones suggested in [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-9), more specifically the ones assuming an external user-agent.

> External user-agent - the native application can capture the response from the authorization server using a **(1)** redirection URI with a scheme registered with the operating system to invoke the client as the handler, **(2)** manual copy-and-paste of the credentials, **(3)** running a local web server, **(4)** installing a user-agent extension, or by **(5)** providing a redirection URI identifying a server-hosted resource under the client's control, which in turn makes the response available to the native application.

**Option 1:**

You configure a redirect using a custom scheme that your Android application registered, this way your application gets called when an external user-agent, the browser, receives a response indicating a redirect to your scheme. Given, there a few Android applications out there :), the scheme should be pretty unique. A recommendation is to use the reverse domain name notation for a domain you own, for example if you owned "app.example.com" the scheme could be "com.example.app".

**Option 2:**

You redirect somewhere that just shows a pretty page with the code and ask the user to input it manually in your application.

**Option 3:**

Your application starts a local web server and you configure the redirect to be something along the lines `http://localhost:[port]/`. Here you there might be issues with port conflicts if multiple applications decide to use the same one.

**Option 4:**

By installing a user-agent extension you would have code running with the browser and that could communicate the code automatically to your applications, more for desktop scenarios.

**Option 5:**

You configure a redirection URI that points to some server-side code you host and that your client Android application is aware of so that it can grab the code from that URL.

---

for much more information on this topic, check: [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-04)

As a final note, using the `file` URL scheme will not be an option. Additionally, if you don't want to go full server-side on the options that require some logic on the server, you can accomplish the same using much less lines of code by writing something as a [Webtask](https://webtask.io/) (be sure to use a custom domain).

**Disclosure**: I'm an Auth0 engineer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! I will tell you asap if this worked for me or not.

Comment: How can I configure a custom scheme like "com.example.app" ? Because this is a native/hybrid android application, I have not a registered domain. The only way, that I am aware of, to access my app is the "not an option" file URL.

Comment: It's just a naming convention, you can ask to register a scheme with the name you want. The convention is just to reduce the likelihood of two apps registering the same scheme.

Comment: Yes, so now I just need to found out how to register a URI scheme in a cordova app. Just to be sure I have understoud the option 1 : if I set and use the new URI scheme in my redirectUri parameter, my "not allowed to load local resource" will be fixed ?

Comment: Yep, and your application should be called when the redirect with the scheme is executed. About how to do it in Android+Cordova I wont't be of much help.

Comment: I just marked your answer as accepted. No more `Not allowed to load local resource` with a custom URL scheme. But now, I am stuck with the right redirect_uri to write, because `com.example.app://` is not accepted as a right URI, and `com.example.app://home` neither. I do not know what to put behind the `://` but this is for another stack! Thanks again for your help !